# Nuxt2 Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, nuxt.js

Im having problem with using **nuxt** and **bootstrap**
I successfully imported **bootstrap** but seems there are glitch/issues that is showing,
One of this is, its **jQuery** functionalities are not working such as: Modal, Tabs, Tooltips and others,

My question is, how to make this work?
Below are the configurations I did:
@/plugins/bootstrap.js

```js
// Include bootstrap JS only
if (process.BROWSER_BUILD) {
    require('jquery')
    require('popper.js')
    require('bootstrap')
}
```

nuxt.config.js

```js
plugins: [
   ...
   {src: '@/plugins/bootstrap.js', mode: 'client'},
   ...
],

...

build: {
   ...
   vendor: ['jquery', 'bootstrap', 'vue-back-top'],
   plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
         $: 'jquery',
         jQuery: 'jquery',
         'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
      })
   ]
}
```

Im using Nuxt.js@v2.14.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a fix on this,
I added bootstrap on the custom javascript

assets/js/bootstrap.js

```js
import $ from 'jquery';

if(process.browser){
   require('bootstrap')
}
```

nuxt.config.js

```js
...
plugins: [
   ...
   { src: '~assets/master/master.js', ssr: false },
   ...
]
```